# Is there a way to nest a recursive function that updates a list with outer enclosing scope?

Tags: python-3.x, scope

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

> Given the root of a binary tree, construct a 0-indexed m x n string matrix res that represents a formatted layout of the tree. The formatted layout matrix should be constructed using the following rules:
>
> The height of the tree is height and the number of rows m should be equal to height + 1.
> The number of columns n should be equal to 2**(height+1) - 1.
> Place the root node in the middle of the top row (more formally, at location res[0][(n-1)/2]).
> For each node that has been placed in the matrix at position res[r][c], place its left child at res[r+1][c-2height-r-1] and its right child at res[r+1][c+2**(height-r-1)].
> Continue this process until all the nodes in the tree have been placed.
> Any empty cells should contain the empty string "".
> Return the constructed matrix res.

This is my code:

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
def find_h(node: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
    if not node:
        return 0
    return 1 + max(find_h(node.left), find_h(node.right))
class Solution:
    def printTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[List[str]]:
        height = find_h(root)
        res = [['' for _ in range(2 ** height - 1)] for _ in range(height)]
        def dispNode(node: Optional[TreeNode], r: int, c: int):
            res[r][c] = str(node.val)
            if node.left:
                dispNode(node.left, r + 1, c - 2**(height-r-2))
            if node.right:
                dispNode(node.right, r + 1, c + 2**(height-r+2))
        dispNode(root, 0, 2**(height - 1) - 1)
        return res
```

I get an index out of bounds error and if I use a try-except block on the `res[r][c] = str(node.val)` line, I still only get the left nodes only. Is there something wrong with the way variable scopes are working?

Comment: I don't think this is related to scope. The issue is that you gave the wrong input to display the right node. It should be `dispNode(node.right, r + 1, c + 2**(height-r-2))`

Comment: And for those interested, here is the [link to the original problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-binary-tree/)

Comment: @FanchenBao yes, very silly of me, thank you!